Table alignment in vscode tree view
I have custom tree view and I want to turn this into something like a table structure.
due to the fact that non-monospace fonts are used, this cannot be achieved with simple spaces / tabs.
That is, turn this:

into this

How can this be done?

use a WebviewView you have total control of the look

@rioV8, yeap, i know, but i want to reach out with minimal effort.

what you want is a simple HTML rendering of a table from the data you have in a list, add a bit of CSS/jQuery for the folding.
